# SQL WHERE Statement is wrong

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

```
$sql = 'SELECT
    id,
    DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d.%m.%Y - %H.%i Uhr") AS dat,
    user1,
    user2,
    p_user1,
    p_user2,
    be_user1,
    be_user2,
    win
FROM
    kok_1on1_matches
WHERE
    user1="$user"
OR 
    user2="$user"';
```

What is wrong with the WHERE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use single quote ( ' ) that is why your variable is still a string and not a variable.